# Conditional statement to classify 2 functions (Using field value in firebase/Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want conditional statement to classify 2 functions with data from field as "dropdowncompany" in collections as "pr_details", so they're two value in this field

1. `"dropdowncompany":"ซินเนติก"`
2. `"dropdowncompany":"ซินโนวิค"`

**Examples**
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

That I want to really required is the condition statement function that

1. `if ("dropdowncompany" == "ซินเนติก")` --> return Function name as "OverviewPurchase()" (Company name Synatic with blue box)
2. `if ("dropdowncompany" == "ซินโนวิค")` --> return Function name as "OverviewPurchase1()" (Company name Synovic with green box)

**OverviewPurchase function**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverviewPurchase extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverviewPurchase({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverviewPurchase> createState() => _OverviewPurchaseState();
}

class _OverviewPurchaseState extends State<OverviewPurchase> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream:
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("pr_details").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
              child: Container(
                width: size.width * 0.2,
                child: ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Card(
                          borderOnForeground: true,
                          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent[100],
                          child: ListTile(
                              leading: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt_outlined),
                                iconSize: 30,
                              ),
                              title: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Chip(
                                    label: Text("ใบขอซื้อ Synatic"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              subtitle: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(document["purchase_req"]),
                                  Text("บริษัท  :  " +
                                      document["dropdowncompany"]),
                                  Text("แผนก  :  " + document["dropdowndep"]),
                                  Text("ประเภทงาน  :  " +
                                      document["dropdownwork"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "ชื่อ-นามสกุล  :  " + document["fsname"]),
                                  //Text("แผนก  :  " + document["department"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "วันที่เขียน  :  " + document["date_pr"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "จำนวนรายการ  :  ${int.parse((document['number1']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number2']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number3']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number4']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number5']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number6']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number7']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number8']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number9']).length.toString()) + (int.parse((document['number10']).length.toString()) - 1)}")
                                ],
                              ))),
                    ],
                  );
                }).toList()),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**OverviewPurchase1 function**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverviewPurchase1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverviewPurchase1({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverviewPurchase1> createState() => _OverviewPurchase1State();
}

class _OverviewPurchase1State extends State<OverviewPurchase1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream:
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("pr_details").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
              child: Container(
                width: size.width * 0.2,
                child: ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Card(
                          borderOnForeground: true,
                          color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
                          child: ListTile(
                              leading: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt_outlined),
                                iconSize: 30,
                              ),
                              title: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Chip(
                                    label: Text("ใบขอซื้อ Synovic"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              subtitle: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(document["purchase_req"]),
                                  Text("บริษัท  :  " +
                                      document["dropdowncompany"]),
                                  Text("แผนก  :  " + document["dropdowndep"]),
                                  Text("ประเภทงาน  :  " +
                                      document["dropdownwork"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "ชื่อ-นามสกุล  :  " + document["fsname"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "วันที่เขียน  :  " + document["date_pr"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "จำนวนรายการ  :  ${int.parse((document['number1']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number2']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number3']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number4']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number5']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number6']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number7']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number8']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number9']).length.toString()) + (int.parse((document['number10']).length.toString()) - 1)}")
                                ],
                              ))),
                    ],
                  );
                }).toList()),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Finally the output should be this guild pic

[image]

Comment: Please provide the statement where will you be calling the functions

Comment: 1. I'll create my new dart file (name.dart) and build the stateful widget to receive it
the name of class is Divided1() 

After that , i will call Divided1() in body : TabBarview(children : [])

Comment: The type of statement if can using if-statement it's better

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand your question. Based on my understanding, if companyName = 'A' then display data in a blue container, & if companyName = 'B', then display data in a green container.
I ran a diff checker in both the files, only difference is color & title.

```
color: document["dropdowncompany"] == 'ซินเนติก' ? Colors.lightBlueAccent[100] : Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
```

This is the change to be done. You can do similar change for title. Also, you don't need to make 2 widgets. Only 1 is needed

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverviewPurchase extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverviewPurchase({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverviewPurchase> createState() => _OverviewPurchaseState();
}

class _OverviewPurchaseState extends State<OverviewPurchase> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream:
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("pr_details").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
              child: Container(
                width: size.width * 0.2,
                child: ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Card(
                          borderOnForeground: true,
                         color: document["dropdowncompany"] == 'ซินเนติก' ? Colors.lightBlueAccent[100] : Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
                          child: ListTile(
                              leading: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt_outlined),
                                iconSize: 30,
                              ),
                              title: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Chip(
                                    label: Text("ใบขอซื้อ Synatic"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              subtitle: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(document["purchase_req"]),
                                  Text("บริษัท  :  " +
                                      document["dropdowncompany"]),
                                  Text("แผนก  :  " + document["dropdowndep"]),
                                  Text("ประเภทงาน  :  " +
                                      document["dropdownwork"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "ชื่อ-นามสกุล  :  " + document["fsname"]),
                                  //Text("แผนก  :  " + document["department"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "วันที่เขียน  :  " + document["date_pr"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "จำนวนรายการ  :  ${int.parse((document['number1']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number2']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number3']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number4']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number5']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number6']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number7']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number8']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number9']).length.toString()) + (int.parse((document['number10']).length.toString()) - 1)}")
                                ],
                              ))),
                    ],
                  );
                }).toList()),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: sry to reply late, so I'll try it tomorrow and give the result below this comment, thanks a lot :).

Comment: Welcome, you can mark my reply as accepted answer & upvote it. Thanks :)